# How do I test view that uses controllerAs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test view of my controller but I cannot get this to work.
When I try simple template as`<h1>test</h1>` it works but when template is using `controllerAs` syntax I get `Expected undefined to contain 'test'.`
I did some research and `transcludeControllers` should deal with this but it don't. My test look like this:

```
 it('should show test section', () => {
            let candidatesCtrl = $controller('CandidatesController', mock);
            candidatesCtrl.loading = false;
            let scope = $rootScope.$new();

            let linkFn = $compile('<h1 ng-if="!candidatesCtrl.loading">test</h1>');

            let view = linkFn(scope,
                undefined, {
                    transcludeControllers: {
                        CandidatesController: {
                            instance: candidatesCtrl
                        }
                    }
                });

            scope.$digest();
            let templateAsHtml = view.html();
            expect(templateAsHtml).toContain('test');

        });
```

How do I get this to work? I'm using AngularJS `1.6.3` and Jasmine/Karma combo.

Comment: Did you try `$controller('CandidatesController as candidatesCtrl', mock);`?

Comment: Unfortunately it also doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I was looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26404453/4074045